# Why does my vector not update with the changes I make to its elements?

Tags: c++, oop, std

I have a class that uses a vector to store a set of objects which have unsigned longs. One of the operations on that class is to change the stored u_long of an element by OR-ing it with another u_long.

If I `cout` right after I do the OR, it shows that the number was changed. However, if I go back and `cout` the elements from the vector, it does not show that any change was made. What am I missing here?

**Class Definitions**

```
class ULBox {
public:
    ULBox(std::string s) {
        label = s;
    };

    ~ULBox(){};

    std::string getLabel(){
        return label;
    };

    void setNumber(unsigned long n) {
        number |= n;
    };

    unsigned long getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

private:
    std::string label;
    unsigned long number;
};

class BoxList {
public:
    BoxList() {};
    ~BoxList() {};

    bool addBox(std::string label) {
        ULBox newBox(label);
        boxes.push_back(newBox);
        return true;
    };

    bool updateBoxNums(unsigned long num) {
        int i = 1;
        for(auto box: boxes) {
            box.setNumber(num+i);
            std::cout << box.getNumber() << std::endl;
            i++;
        };
        return true;
    };

    void printBoxes() {
        for(auto box: boxes) {
            std::cout << box.getLabel() << ": " << box.getNumber() << std::endl;
        };
    };

private:
    std::vector<ULBox> boxes;
};
```

**Main Function**

```
int main(void) {
    BoxList b_list;

    b_list.addBox("first");
    b_list.addBox("second");
    b_list.addBox("third");

    b_list.updateBoxNums(2);

    b_list.printBoxes();

};
```

**Output**
[output displaying 3, 4, 5 and then 0s where there should be another 3, 4, 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2NXi.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
for(auto box: boxes) {
    box.setNumber(num+i);
    std::cout << box.getNumber() << std::endl;
    i++;
};
```

`box` is a copy of the item in `boxes`. It is not a reference to the item in `boxes`. You are just modifying the copy after that. Use `auto& box`.

```
for(auto& box: boxes) {
    box.setNumber(num+i);
    std::cout << box.getNumber() << std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge headache; I guess I should go back and dig into the ranged-for spec.

Comment: @AlexMozeak, it's combination of `auto` and the range-`for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looping by reference. That's because `auto` is never a reference unless you explicitly make it one. So if you ever intend to edit the actual item you are looping, you will need to do so by reference. That means code like this:

```
auto box: boxes
```

should be:

```
auto& box: boxes
```